# Как сделать так, чтобы файл не создавался физически?

Tags: c#, файлы

```
       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");

        sw.WriteLine("Какой-то текст");
        sw.Close();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");

        source = "";

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                source += sr.ReadLine();
            }

        sr.Close();
```

Ни в коем случае ни доводить это до банальной строки! А именно сделать так чтобы было все тоже самое, только файл физически не создавался?

**upd** [1]

сделал через MemoryStream

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{

    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    sw.Write(ParsedHtmlFromURL); // тут или WriteLine, без разницы
    ms.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    source = sr.ReadToEnd();

}
```

в итоге у меня теперь регулярка не может пройтись по source. Т.е. оно как-то не так записывается.

**upd** [2]
Если это так критично, показываю код более широко, с регуляркой:

```
string pattern = @"<h5>(.+?)</h5>";

            source = "";

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

                sw.WriteLine(htmlFromURL);

                sw.Flush();

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

                source = sr.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline ))
                {

                        listBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

                } 
    MessageBox.Show(source); // это выведет мне вполне адекватный исходник
```

**upd** [3] Ну а htmlFromURL берется вот так:

```
    private string getHtml(string args)
    {

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        client.Headers.Add("charset", "UTF-8");

        string s = "";
        Stream data;

        try
        {
           data = client.OpenRead(args);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return s;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

        s = reader.ReadToEnd();

        data.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return s;

    }
```

**upd** [4] а вот не срабатывает так, не знаю уже 100 раз проверил, пашет только такой вариант:

```
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");

            sw.WriteLine(htmlFromURL);
            sw.Close();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");

            source = "";

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
               source += sr.ReadLine();
            }

            sr.Close();

            string pattern = @"<h5>(.+?)</h5>";

            // вот тут если сразу чере метод вместо source, то не сработает
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline))
            {

                    listBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

            }
```

**upd** [5] Проблема была дей-но с переходами на новую строку, после

```
htmlFromURL.Replace("\n"," ")
```

все заработало.

Comment: вот не знаю почему так, через физический файл срабатывает регулярка, а через MemoryStream нет.

Comment: А зачем вообще гонять через стрим? почему не сделать :

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(htmlFromURL, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline ))
                {

                        listBox1.Items.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

                }

Comment: см. **upd** [4].

Comment: Кстати, дело с файлом скорее всего в том что из файла Вы читаете по строкам, при этом знаки переноса строк не включаются в обрабатываемую строку, а в случае с мемори стримом - включаются.

Comment: попробуйте сделать :

  htmlFromURL.Replace("\n"," ")

Comment: Если я уберу RegexOptions.Multiline, то мне это ничего ни даст, в том-то и дело.

Comment: Чад, ты гений. А как говорится все гениальное просто!

Comment: ед отличиие входных данных для регэкспа - это то что через файл вы убираете символы \n\r а через стрим и напрямую строку - они есть. Так что в этом надо копаться.

Comment: В итоге весь этот сырбор с MemoryStream и физическими файлами сам собой отпал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо добавить Flush():

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
            sw.Write("Какой-то текст"); // тут или WriteLine, без разницы
            sw.Flush();//Вот это надо добавить, тогда всё работает. Можно ещё поиграться со свойством autoFlush
            ms.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            var source = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

Кстати, дело с файлом скорее всего в том что из файла Вы читаете по строкам, при этом знаки переноса строк не включаются в обрабатываемую строку, а в случае с MemoryStream - включаются.

Comment: увы, Flush() не помог, хотя я сделал MessageBox.Show(source) мне вывело весь исходник. Может это дей-но кодировка, тогда как можно кодировку примусово изменить переменной source?

Comment: StreamWriter и StreamReader имеют вторым параметром конструктора Encoding, выставите в Encoding.Utf8 например. Но дело скорее всего в регулярке - надо её разбирать.

Comment: она работает 100%, я специально проверял, вручную ввел source ="кусочек html такой же самый как и с настоящей страницы" и этот мизер распарсил, и оно нормально отреагирывало.

Comment: Если мессажд бокс отобразил то что надо, а регулярга не отработала, то проблема наверное в регулярке? или в способе её применения.

Comment: добавил кодировки(UTF-8) вторыми параметрами, в итоге при записи в файл выдается ошибка: 

    sw.WriteLine(htmlFromURL, Encoding.UTF8);

`Входная строка имела неверный формат.`

Comment: Значит кодировка строки не та, откуда получается htmlFromURL?

Comment: секунду еще upd[3] добавлю.

Comment: @Tolbase, так в чём в итоге была проблема с регэкспом?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать MemoryStream. Это поток, который позволяет записывать и читать данные в буфере в памяти, т.е. очень похоже на работу с файлом, но без участия файловой системы.

Comment: я как раз через него и попробовал, я парсю одну страницу, но через MemoryStream и с простыми строками моя регулярка просто напросто не срабатывает, только когда забью исходник html в физический файл и оттуда считаю, то только тогда смогу распарсить переменную source, см. дополнение.

Comment: я ж говорю с физическим файлом работает. А вот на счет кодировки вполне может быть, но у меня при взятии html в headers.add("charset","UTF-8") и другой кодировки навряд ли там предвидется.

Comment: Тут дело не в кодировке, я в ответе написал в чём дело. Видимо райтер не сразу пишет, надо доки читать почему именно надо так.

Comment: А AutoFlush как использовать?

Comment: У StreamWriter выставить свойство AutoFlush, Но надо посмотреть в каких случаях он это ауто делает.

Comment: я и false и true ему ставил, безполезно.